# removing rows between certain cells containing text - excel

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I'm totally new to any kind of programming but I'm trying to remove all rows between two cells containing certain text, then repeat it this through all (~130k rows) in the spreadsheet.

**Example**

I want to remove all rows between cell B2 and B7, based on the text in those cells
[image: Example, I want to remove all rows between cell B2 and B7, based on the text in those cells]

Is there a way a non-programmer might be able to do this? :)

Comment: Welcome to SO...if i understood your question do you want remove all rows between cells Standard run->Setup run included?

Answer (score 0):

In this example i suppose that in Column B there aren't two "consecutive Standard run->Setup run" and viceversa.

initial sheet:

[image]

final sheet

[image]

This is the code:

```
Sub test()
'remove cells between two cells Standard run->Setup run and Setup run->Standard run

Dim count, i, numCols As Long
Dim startRemove, endRemove, startText, endText As String
Dim rng As Range

startText = "Standard run->Setup run" 'text where we begin to remove the cells
endText = "Setup run->Standard run" ' text where we finish to remove the cells


startRemove = "" 'in this variable we'll put the cell address of Standard run->Setup run Cells(2, 7).Address
endRemove = "" 'in this variable we'll put the cell address of Setup run->Standard run Cells(7, 7).Address

'-----control column B
'count how many rows
numCols = Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count

For i = 1 To numCols

   If Cells(i, 2) = startText Then ' control if current cell has Standard run->Setup run

        startRemove = Cells(i, 2).Address

    ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = endText Then ' control if current cell has Setup run->Standard run

        endRemove = Cells(i, 2).Address

        Range(startRemove & ":" & endRemove).Delete
        startRemove = ""
        endRemove = ""
    End If
Next i
Range("B1:B" & numCols).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp ' delete empty rows created

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks for a great answer!

I cant really get it to work just yet. When I run it it responds no cells could be found so I guess I'm doing something wrong here (Run-time error '1004': No cells were found.)

The cell adress of standard run -> setup run is C21 so I put (21,3) in the reference, is this correct way to do it? And then the same procedure for Setup run -> standard run.

Like this:
startRemove = "(21, 3)" 
endRemove = "(26, 3)"

Comment: Controllo the text cella...i wrote Standard run->Set-up run without the space...control in tour cell how it is write...and after copy and paste into variabile startText and endText...keep me update...

Comment: Into startRemove there is the address example C21

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that does not require VBA

[image]

I have inserted a formula in column C, you can apply a filter to remove the rows.

The formula in cell C2 is

```
=IF(B2="Standard run->Setup run","start",IF(B2="Setup run->Standard run","end",IF(C1="start","remove",IF(C1="end","do not remove",C1))))
```